# How to connect sql server to mojo portal with jQuery sqlrun()

Tags: .net

I am working in a mojoportal where I need to connect jquery with sql by just calling the function `sqlRun();`.

For example, we can take a div: We have to use the div id and using this call sql run, this will execute a procedure and we will get the result in the front end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll find you are more likely to receive good answers if you show us or explain what you've already tried. Take a look at [ask] for some guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, nor should it be possible. What you are asking for is to be able to submit a SQL query back to the server from a client-side script which makes SQL Injection a big probability.

You can create code which will run server-side and still communicate with client-side scripts (jQuery in your case). Take a look at the "[Adding Custom JavaScript](http://www.mojoportal.com/adding-custom-javascript.aspx)" article on the mojoPortal site for more information on this.